# Make a MUI v4 Grid element appear with CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to make use of the breakpoints in the  component from MUI v4 to let items of my Grid-System appear and disappear.

How can I make a smooth CSS transition for `b` from 0px to to definied breakpoint size 3 for `xl`? it works for me when I use %, but I can't figure out how to achieve the same with a Grid. It wont have width 0px

eg:

```
let show = true; //reactUseState

const toggle = (p) => {
  return(!p);
}

<Grid container direction="row>
  <Grid id="a" item xl={show?12:9}>{children}</Grid>
  <Grid id="b" item xl={show?false:3}>{otherchildren}</Grid>
</Grid>

<Button onClick={() => toggle(show)}>Show 1 or 2 items</Grid>
```

I hope someone knows the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Grid container direction="row">
  <Grid className="right" id="b" item lg={show ? 12 : 9}>{'otherchildren'}</Grid>
  <Grid className={show? "left left-hide" : "left"} id="a" item lg={3}>{'children'}</Grid>
</Grid>
```

css

```
.right {
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}

.left {
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-hide {
  flex-basis: 0% !important;
}
```

Comment: My basic problem is that Grid b always has a width. It is never like: 'display:none'. So this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. try it.